# How do I get more information after subscribing?

Tags: paypal

I don't know how to get more information after subscription.

The following returns an error:

```js
paypal.Buttons({
  createSubscription: function (data, actions) {
    console.log(data)
    return actions.subscription.create({
      'plan_id': PP_PLAN_ID
    })
  },
  onApprove: function (data, actions) {
    console.log(data)
    fetch(`https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/${data.subscriptionID}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${data.facilitatorAccessToken}`
      }
    })
    .then((r) => {
        return r.json()
    })
    .then((r) => {
    console.log(r)
    })
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container')
```

Error response

```
{
  "name": "NOT_AUTHORIZED",
  "message": "Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.",
  "debug_id": "e0ba8b67ee540",
  "details": [
    {
      "issue": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
      "description": "You do not have permission to access or perform operations on this resource."
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#NOT_AUTHORIZED",
      "rel": "information_link",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm guessing some configuration is missing because of the permission error. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a client-side operation, and a ClientID access token will not have permission.

You need to obtain the access token from a server, using a ClientID and Secret: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-an-access-token

Comment: Reading the documentation mistakenly, sure. Just make sure the API call is done from your own server, since the 'secret' (and access tokens generated with the secret) should never be in the client web browser, for security reasons. They are for server-side use only.